# Execute PHP script from python

Tags: php, python

I try to run my php script from python.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
require '../functions/server_info.php';
require ('../functions/functions.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
$input_data_trunk = array();
$input_data_trunk['ami_category']="TRK-IPU";
$IP = "192.168.1.200";  
conf_sip_action($input_data_trunk, 'new', 'trunk');
echo "done";
?>
```

Then I write python code i execute this script, but I have error like this:`

```
PHP Warning:  require(../functions/server_info.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/IPU-GUI/website2/LTU_trunk.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '../functions/server_info.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/IPU-GUI/website2/LTU_trunk.php on line 2
```

Here is my python code (just execute script):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call( ["/usr/bin/php", "/var/www/html/IPU-GUI/website2/LTU_trunk.php"] )
```

I am looking for help.

Thanks in advance.

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute php code in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984287/execute-php-code-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require ..` is relative to the current working directory/the PATH setting, **not the current PHP file**. When executing from Python, the working directory will be either undefined or simply different from what you might expect. Use an absolute import path/relative to the file:

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/functions/server_info.php';
```