# Python Web Server with PHP code?

Tags: php, python, web, server

Can I load PHP to a Python Web Server or it is impossible?

I want to use Python for Web Server and PHP, but PHP is loading to notes in HTML.

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984287/execute-php-code-in-python

Comment: Maybe your mime types are misconfigured?

Try [these tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get more, better, and faster answers.