# Python script run in-line php syntax, no separate file

Tags: php, python

Is there a way, in Python, to run a single php syntax command? I know I can just run `os.system` to call a separate php file but that seem excessive. So I want no separate file if possible.

Something similar to:

```
if send_mail == True:
   #something to run single line php: mail($to,$txt,$subject)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute php code in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984287/execute-php-code-in-python)

Comment: I want to do no separate file if possible.

Comment: @PhantomQuest How would `$to`, `$txt`, and `$subject` be getting values?

Comment: @PatrickQ Hard coding

Comment: @PhantomQuest If you don't want to import any modules, then `os.system` is all you have. Is there a particular reason *why* you don't want to import anything, even though `subprocess` is part of the python standard library (and thus comes pre-installed, along with all the other built-in tools)?

Comment: It feels excessive to write a single line of php in an entire file then export that out. Sorta like how we use lambda functions. And overall curious if its possible to run separate languages (though I can see why not). Thought there might be a library for that.

Comment: @PhantomQuest Just to clarify, when you are objecting to using "separate file", are you objecting to the usage of `subprocess` completely or are you objecting to the call to a PHP file (such as `/path/to/your/script.php`) within the `subprocess.call` command?

Comment: Just the calling of the PHP file. I'm really looking for a function in Python that will let me pass `mail('someone@email.com','txt','subject')` directly.

Comment: In that case, the suggested duplicate is still applicable, you just need to use `php -r 'command here';`

Comment: So would final syntax be `subprocess.call('php -r mail('someone@email.com','txt','subject')')`

Comment: @PhantomQuest No, that's going to give you mismatched quoting issues.  I don't use Python much, but it would probably be something like either `subprocess.call('php -r \'mail("someone@email.com","txt","subject")\');')` or `subprocess.call('php -r "mail(\'someone@email.com\',\'txt\',\'subject\'\)");'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess` library for doing this.

For example:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call("php /path to php file")
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This requires a call to a separate file, which I don't want if possible