# How can i run a php function in python?

Tags: python, php, function

for some reasons, i have to run a php function in python.

However, i realized that it's beyond my limit.

So, i'm asking for help here.

below is the code

```
function munja_send($mtype, $name, $phone, $msg, $callback, $contents) {
$host = "www.sendgo.co.kr";
$id = ""; // id
$pass = ""; // password
$param = "remote_id=".$id;
$param .= "&remote_pass=".$pass;
$param .= "&remote_name=".$name;
$param .= "&remote_phone=".$phone; //cellphone number
$param .= "&remote_callback=".$callback; // my cellphone number
$param .= "&remote_msg=".$msg; // message
$param .= "&remote_contents=".$contents; // image
if ($mtype == "lms") {
$path = "/Remote/RemoteMms.html";
} else {
$path = "/Remote/RemoteSms.html";
}
$fp = @fsockopen($host,80,$errno,$errstr,30);
$return = "";
if (!$fp) {
echo $errstr."(".$errno.")";
} else {
fputs($fp, "POST ".$path." HTTP/1.1\r\n");
9
fputs($fp, "Host: ".$host."\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($param)."\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
fputs($fp, $param."\r\n\r\n");
while(!feof($fp)) $return .= fgets($fp,4096);
}
fclose ($fp);
$_temp_array = explode("\r\n\r\n", $return);
$_temp_array2 = explode("\r\n", $_temp_array[1]);
if (sizeof($_temp_array2) > 1) {
$return_string = $_temp_array2[1];
} else {
$return_string = $_temp_array2[0];
}
return $return_string;
}
```

i would be glad if anyone can show me a way.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

according to the internet, you can use subprocess and then execute the PHP script

```
import subprocess
    
    # if the script don't need output.
    subprocess.call("php /path/to/your/script.php")
    
    # if you want output
    proc = subprocess.Popen("php /path/to/your/script.php", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    script_response = proc.stdout.read()
```

Comment: Can you fix your import indent please?

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PHP, but based on my understanding, here should be a raw line-for-line translation of the code you provided, from PHP to python. I've preserved your existing comments, and added new ones for clarification in places where I was unsure or where you might want to change.

It should be pretty straightforward to follow - the difference is mostly in syntax (e.g. `+` for concatenation instead of `.`), and in converting `str` to `bytes` and vice versa.

```py
import socket

def munja_send(mtype, name, phone, msg, callback, contents):
    host = "www.sendgo.co.kr"
    remote_id = ""  # id  (changed the variable name, since `id` is also a builtin function)
    password = ""  # password  (`pass` is a reserved keyword in python)
    param = "remote_id=" + remote_id
    param += "&remote_pass=" + password
    param += "&remote_name=" + name
    param += "&remote_phone=" + phone  # cellphone number
    param += "&remote_callback=" + callback  # my cellphone number
    param += "&remote_msg=" + msg  # message
    param += "&remote_contents=" + contents  # image
    if mtype == "lms"
        path = "/Remote/RemoteMms.html"
    else:
        path = "/Remote/RemoteSms.html"
    socket.settimeout(30)
    # change these parameters as necessary for your desired outcome
    fp = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    errno = fp.connect_ex((host, 80))
    if errno != 0:
        # I'm not sure where errmsg comes from in php or how to get it in python
        # errno should be the same, though, as it refers to the same system call error code
        print("Error(" + errno + ")")
    else:
        returnstr = b""
        fp.send("POST " + path + "HTTP/1.1\r\n")
        fp.send("Host: " + host + "\r\n")
        fp.send("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n")
        # for accuracy, we convert param to bytes using utf-8 encoding
        # before checking its length. Change the encoding as necessary for accuracy
        fp.send("Content-length: " + str(len(bytes(param, 'utf-8'))) + "\r\n")
        fp.send("Connection: close\r\n\r\n")
        fp.send(param + "\r\n\r\n")
        while (data := fp.recv(4096)):
            # fp.recv() should return an empty string if eof has been hit
            returnstr += data
    fp.close()
    _temp_array = returnstr.split(b'\r\n\r\n')
    _temp_array2 = _temp_array[1].split(b'\r\n')
    if len(temp_array2) > 1:
        return_string = _temp_array2[1]
    else:
        return_string = _temp_array2[0]
    # here I'm converting the raw bytes to a python string, using encoding
    # utf-8 by default. Replace with your desired encoding  if necessary
    # or just remove the `.decode()` call if you're fine with returning a
    # bytestring instead of a regular string
    return return_string.decode('utf-8')
```

**If possible, you should probably use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to execute your php code directly**, as other answers suggest, as straight-up translating code is often error-prone and has slightly different behavior (case in point, the lack of `errmsg` and probably different error handling in general, and maybe encoding issues in the above snippet). But if that's not possible, then hopefully this will help.

Answer (score -1):

PHP code can be executed in python using libraries **subprocess or php.py** based on the situation.
Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984287/execute-php-code-in-python#:%7E:text=You%20can%20simply%20execute%20the%20php%20executable%20from%20Python.&text=If%20you%20can%20run%20the,then%20you%20can%20use%20urllib.) for further details.