# Integration of third party authentication on Django Project

Tags: php, python-3.x, django, authentication

I have an authentication system that is built in PHP for my clients to log in using only one login credential to access different products. Mostly my web pages are written in PHP so it is easy to integrate different PHP products with the same authentication. Now I have a Django webpage and want to authenticate my clients with the same authentication system that is written in PHP, is it possible?

I have three PHP files which help me with the authentication can I directly tell my Django to use these files for authentication and after success redirect to the webpage to use different features inside the webpage?

Comment: might helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984287/execute-php-code-in-python

Comment: will it be very difficult to implement those in Django? Django is very flexible when it comes to custom authentication: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/